# Effects of events in Angel to the Buffy Storyline

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer, angel

I have re-watched the Buffy Series and the Angel spin off afterwards. The last 4 seasons of Buffy and the first 4 seasons of Angel were happening concurrently. There were also a few intersections between series storyline in this time:

> Like Buffy sending the gem of Amara to Angel, Angel going to Sunnydale to save Buffy, Angel finding out about Buffys death, Faith going to LA after the body swap with Buffy...

In Season 4 of Angel, Jasmine brings world peace temporarily

> before Angel kills her.

In the last Episode of Season 4, Angel gets some intel about the events happening  in Sunnydale (during the last season of Buffy). So clearly the "world peace time span" occurs before the finale of Buffy, yet there was no peace in Sunnydale.

So my question is why were Sunnydale and the Scoobies & Slayers not affected by the world peace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the hell mouth acts like a pocket dimension. Same reason that the three dweeb are able to make super science androids and other technology. The hell mouth operates differently than normal earth space and things that affect it don't necessarily affect the outside, or vise-versa There is also signs that this is what happened to LA, as told in the canon comics.

Furthermore, Jasmine never actually took over the whole world yet. People need to see or hear her to fall under her power. Much of LA was affected, but Angel stopped this from happening to the world by interrupting the broadcast that Jasmine was going to use. It was last minute.

Comment: I like this answer and I wonder if there is any support for it or if it is an understanding or conjecture gleaned from primary sources.

Comment: @todd the episode where Angel stops the world wide broadcast.

Comment: I was thinking more about the first paragraph of the hell mouth not only attracting demons but also altering reality slightly in its vicinity.