# Crossover episodes that have title cards for both series?

Tags: analysis, production, chronology, crossovers

Usually a crossover episode is clearly a **Series A** episode with a plot that includes visiting **Series B** characters.

Are there any cases where a crossover episode is a mainline numbered episode of *both* series?

Something like the two items below both being the exact same episode:

> `Series A - S03E06 - "That Crossover Episode"`
> `Series B - S01E01 - "That Crossover Episode"`

There are plenty of cases where crossovers exist in the "continuity" of both shows, but what I'm looking for is a single episode that is an official numbered episode of *both* Series A and Series B.

[The Jetsons Meet the Flintstones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Jetsons_Meet_the_Flintstones) would qualify. But that's more of a TV-movie and/or dedicated special rather than a true episode of either show.

Are there any other cases where a single episode exists as an episode in the continuity of both shows? Preferably with shown title cards / credits for both.

Comment: This happened in at least one Buffy/Angel season, where Willow leaves in an episode of Buffy, arrives in the next episode of Angel, and then returns to Buffy with a weapon or so they picked up in the Angel episode. Dunno the exact seasons, though. See for instance http://josswhedon.blogspot.com/2012/04/buffy-and-angel-episode-viewing-order.html or https://www.reddit.com/r/buffy/comments/88a3ju/want_a_different_buffyangel_watch_order_here_ya_go/ and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7890/ and https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/70156/ etc.

Comment: But honestly this feels too broad. I'm sure there are many answers possible (I assume plenty of those DC shows on The CW for instance have overlapping storylines), and thus inevitably you will get multiple answers and that would make this off-topic.

Comment: The CW shows are crossover events, but not really what I'm looking for. I believe each of those is clearly an episode of a single show, with characters from the others appearing.

Comment: I know the Q is now closed, but did you specifically mean the reairing of the same episode with the same episode number in both series. So in your example 3.06 is the same exact episode, in which one series would technically re-air, because both series would technically not be on at the same time? Or just that the cross over happens in two different episodes that just happen to have the same title and episode number? I don't think they would ever do this, because it would be confusing...there would certainly be a "part 1" and "part 2" of such and such 3.06 title...

Comment: @DarthLocke I'm looking for a single episode that is an episode of *both* shows, airing at the same time, that is considered a numbered episode of both. I'm not sure if it even exists, hence the question. Pity that these kind of questions are not allowed here...

Comment: Again it's not clear what you mean. The same exact episode (which would then air twice) or two different episodes (in a shared universe) with the exact same title.

Comment: @DarthLocke The same episode. It doesn't need to air twice, the same episode could air in the same timeslot for both series. Perhaps as a double-length episode.

Comment: Ya, but if it's a crossover event, the shows would never be on at the same time, because they would be owned by the same network/production company. One show/episode would have to air before the other. Now maybe this could happen in the future of streaming platform, but I do not think it has happened yet.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you want, but there was a two-part crossover which started in *Magnum P.I.* and concluded in *Simon  and Simon.* Both were in-continuity episodes of their own series. On their original broadcast, the episodes were shown on the same night,  one immediately after the other.

[Details here](http://www.poobala.com/magnumandsimon.html)

Comment: Another like this was the first Arrow /Flash crossover.  The first part was Flash S01E08 “Flash vs Arrow” aired on 2nd December 2014, concluding with Arrow S03E08 “The Brave and The Bold” airing the following day.

Answer (score 1):

A few months ago I saw the begining of an episode and got interested in seeing how it would turn out, not knowing that it was the start of a three hour story I would feel compelled to watch all of.

It was the October 19 rerun of The crossover event of the *FBI* episode "All That Glitters", Sept. 21, 2021, which continued in the *FBI: Most Wanted* episode "Exposed",Sept. 21, and ended in the *FBI: International* episode "PIlot",  Sept. 21.

But I didn't check to see if the title cards for the 3 episodes included all three series or just one series each.

Here is a link to a list of some examples of tv shows with common coninutity and crossovers:

https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheVerse

In the early 21st century the Disney Channel had a lot of crossover events between various live action shows, though not in the last few years.  This created what is called the DCLAU, or Disney Channel Live Action Universe.

In most cases the crossover events include episodes of different series separately.

But sometimes it is a little different:

> With the Jessie/Good Luck Charlie crossover event "Good Luck Jessie: NYC Christmas" both halves for each series were still produced separately by each series' production staff (with the credits for the second half running halfway through the episode during the obvious transition), but the entire event is considered a single episode, and listed as such in its entirety as the single episode "Good Luck Jessie: NYC Christmas" simultaneously for the production orders for Jessie and Good Luck Charlie (i.e., there are no separately-titled parts making up the whole).

https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Franchise/DisneyChannelLiveActionUniverse

Wikipedia lists "Good Luck Jessie: NYC Christmas", Nov. 29, 2013, as an episode of both *Jessie* (production code 306) and *Good Luck Charlie* (production code 418).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Jessie_episodes

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Good_Luck_Charlie_episodes#Season_4_(2013%E2%80%9314)

And so does the IMDB:

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1865769/episodes?season=3

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1415889/episodes?ref_=tt_eps_sm

There are some websites about tv and/or other media crossovers, shared universes, and spinoffs.  And it is possible that some of those sites might have places for you to ask your question.

https://thetommywestphall.wordpress.com/

https://fictionalcrossover.fandom.com/wiki/Crossover_Wiki

http://poobala.com/crossoverlist.html

I hope this helps.

Comment: That looks like a good example! > *"Notes: This is a combined double-length special episode. The opening credits sequence is a combination of the opening credits sequences of Good Luck Charlie and Jessie, presenting the main cast from both series with the theme songs and visuals from both series interweaved."*